# Which data should I normalize for training a good model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm experimenting with machine learning regressors and I was using the dataset train.csv from the following webpage: https://www.kaggle.com/c/rossmann-store-sales/data?select=train.csv

I was trying to train an SVR but it was taking a lot of time to fit, so I realized the problem is probably because I haven't normalized data.

I know a normal practice to do is to normalize the columns, but I'm not really sure which ones should I apply it to. There are some binary variables and some continuous, and I feel like it would be weird to normalize the binary variables. Is this correct?

The table columns are the following:
[image: Table content]

Open, promo and SchoolHoliday are binary. StateHoliday can take values from 0 to 4.
The other ones are ints (except date obviously).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Store`, `DayOfWeek`, `Open`, `Promo`, `StateHoliday`, `SchoolHoliday` are categorical features. They can be encoded as one-hot-encoded vector using `OneHotEncoder`.

`Sales`, `Customers` are numerical features and can be encoded for example with `StandardScaler`, `RobustScaler` etc.

see scikit-learn preprocessing documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing) for additional transformations.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried both and StandardScaler worked perfectly. OneHotEncoder, on the other hand, brought some problems as it uses a lot of memory and causes google colab to crash when applied to the 'Store' column because of RAM usage (column has 1115 different values). Do you know what else could I use for the categorical features?

Comment: OneHotEncoder is returning a scipy sparse matrix (which is an optimal way to store matrix with lot of zeros). I think that you convert it to numpy array and therefore had RAM issue. The best way would be to create a Pipeline that will transform numerical and categorical variable and then feed them into the model.